# Where is the latest protobuf API for the Kubernetes CRI?

Tags: kubernetes

The protobuf API for the CRI in Kubernetes 1.5 can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.5/pkg/kubelet/api/v1alpha1/runtime/api.proto). Where is the latest version of this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API was [recently](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/33081c1f07be128a89441a39c467b7ea2221b23d#diff-c9533c2c855d722d8416950cff5092a4) broken out to its own repository: [`kubernetes/cri-api`](https://github.com/kubernetes/cri-api).

You can still find the protobuf API within the main repository: [kubernetes/staging/src/k8s.io/cri-api](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/staging/src/k8s.io/cri-api/).